# Finding radius of ellipse at angle a?

Tags: math, trigonometry

I know the centre of an ellipse, **x0** and **y0**. I know its *width* and *height*.

How do I get the radius at any given angle from x0/y0?

Comment: Try asking on math.stackexchange.com. But do a search first. It's probably been answered already.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming question

Comment: this looks like a homework question.

Answer (score 1):

Its conventional to describe an ellipse, centred at x0,y0, whose axes of symmetry are aligned with the coordinate axes by the equation

```
(x-x0)*(x-x0)/(a*a) + (y-y0)*(y-y0)/(b*b) = 1
```

Here a and b are constants that define the size and shape of the ellipse.

To get the width we put y=y0, and then the x values are

```
x = x0 + a
x = x0 - a
```

so the width is

```
w = 2*a
```

Similarly the height is

```
h = 2*b
```

If we have a point x,y on the ellipse and the angle between the x-axis and the vector x0,y0 -> x,y is theta then x,y can be written

```
x = x0 + r*cos(theta)
y = x0 + r*sin(theta)
```

We need to find r so that x,y is on the ellipse. Plugging these values into the equation for the ellipse and simplifying:

```
r = 1.0/hypot( cos(theta)/a, sin(theta)/b)
```

I'm guessing that by radius you mean the distance between x,y and x0,y0. This is r above

Comment: this is not true ... you forgot that if  `a!=b` the angle `theta` is jus a parameter and not the real angle !!! they will be "slightly" off how much depends on eccentricity and angular position itself. first you need to convert real angle to theta using inverse scaling in `b` axis direction on circular point (scale by `a/b` from center) ... and then use `atan2` on the result which will give you your `theta` after applying the parametric ellipse equation the reulting point would be on the original angle

Comment: I said that theta is 'between the x-axis and the vector x0,y0 -> x,y '. Given that, what I said is true. This angle is also known as the geocentric latitude. You appear to be thinking about the geodetic latitude, often just called the latitude. This is the angle between the normal to the ellipse at the point and the x axis.

Comment: no its not, that is true only for circle ... the ellipse is circle scaled down so the original circle become ellipse that stretches the angles (normal too) Here example image: [circle to ellipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCvyu.png) ... the `theta` corresponds to circular angle but the real angle `alpha` is scaled down ... as the `y` axis has radius `a*(b/a)` where `b/a` is the scale ...so you just need to correct like this: `theta = atan2(sin(angle),(a/b)*cos(angle))` where `angle` is the input real angle. feel free to reuse that image in case you want to repair your answer.